# jQuery $(element).html() not working in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a strange problem with IE7. I am loading content in a div element using ajax request. In ajax response html there is a div with id "compare_div" with some content.
When I try to get html using $('#compare_div').html(), it returns null.

Below is my javascript code,

```
function myFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data: data,             
        url  : my_url,
        success : function(response) {
            $('#parent_div').html(response);
            var compare_div_html = $('#compare_div').html();
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {         
            alert(textStatus);
        }       
    });
    return false;   
}
```

I am getting null in compare_div_html variable. This code works fine for all other browser.

Please help.

Comment: What's supposed to be in "#compare_div" ? Because you're filling "#parent_div" with the Ajax response.

Comment: Try doing `alert($('#compare_div').length)` to see if the compare_div actually exists in IE7.

Comment: This may happen if if you have another element with same id try `alert($('[id=compare_div]').length);` and make sure that there is only element with id=compare_div

Comment: My ajax response is something like,
<div>
   ...
   <div id="compare_div">...</div>
</div>

Comment: @Gary Green, $('#compare_div').length returns 0, so I think response is not properly appending to parent div, but it only happens with IE7, it works fine with IE8 and IE9

Comment: I suspect it could be a case-sensitive issue (id's are case sensitive) or that #compare_div just isn't there. Can you do `alert($('body').html().match(/compare_div/i))` just to see if it exists, very crude debug but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

First check the element exists,

if you confirm the same the ensure that data is not empty

if every thing is ok

then try `$('#parent_div',"container").html(response);`

this would solve your problem